# how to change the header and footer of PHPBB forum?

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

can any one help me to change the footer and header of the phpbb forum..

Answer (score 6):

For PHPBB version 3.0.x the header is now at "/styles/[stylename]/template/overall_header.html" and the footer is at "/styles/[stylename]/template/overall_footer.html".

Pete

Answer (score 2):

You need to find /templates/name-of-style-you-use/overall_header.tpl and /templates/name-of-style-you-use/overall_footer.tpl accordingly. You can edit them easily.

Comment: thanks jack :) then can u help me to how to add a new forum or new category in phpbb3

Answer (score 0):

Well you can also just add the following lines to your `styles/<theme>/template/ajax.js` file:

`var copy = $('.copyright').html();
var link = copy.split("<br>").pop();
$('.copyright').html(link);`

Or to remove everything from the footer (incl. the acp link). One liner solution in you javascript file again:

`$('.copyright').css('display','none');`

Regards, Melroy

Comment: Ps. css is also possible: `.copyright { display: none; }`